# Update contacts via Journey Builder in a SC and SFMC 4 Business Units environment

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

In short:

- Salescloud stores data of four subsidiaries. Everyone with its own
  account ID and customers as contacts mapped to the account ID.
- Every subsidiary has a BU in Marketing Cloud
- Currently I do not use a Multi Org Configuration

I'm now trying to enable a subscription process, which can be managed by a Marketing Manager without the use of API and AMPscript

**The problem**

In BU1 I use a smart capture and update or create contacts via Journey Builders Contact Activity. With a lookup on email it seems, that the contact ist created or updated in the account of the right subsidiary.

Doing the same in BU2 does not work. It should happen, that a contact is created or updated at the Account of subsidiary 2. But the lookup on email tries to update the contact which is stored under the Account ID of subsidiary 1.

What can I do here, if I do not want to use API or AMPscript. Is there a way to map the Account IDs to the MIDs of the Marketing Cloud or is it necessary to switch to a Multi org configuration?

Answer (score 0):

As per my awareness, you DO need to do multi org setup as there's no other way you can exchange data between orgs.